# Python - Check if url exists fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

I'm trying to create a python function that will connect to a URL and check if a list of directory's exists on that website. So the input consists of a target and the directory's. My ultimate goal is to write some sort of DirBuster like program.

This is my function untill now:

```
def checkDir(checkDir_target):
    breakurl = urlparse(target)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(breakurl.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', checkDir_target)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.status
    complete = target + x
    if (response.status < 400):
        print(" [X] " + complete)
        global total_resp
        total_resp += 1
        found.append(complete)
    else:
        print(" [ ] " + complete)
```

The only problem I'm having right now is that dynamic created pages like wordpress pages also return HTTP Status 200 codes. So even when I'm testing on a non-existing url the website will still return a HTTP 200 OK.

Example: testing on **www.wordpressexamplesite.com/DIRECTORYTHATDOESNTEXISTS/** gives a HTTP 200 code as well as website URL's that DOES exist.

This means that the whole check in the checkDir function is not doing it's work like I want it to.

Can one of you guys give me some ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: (Please double-check the indentation on your code sample. As it stands, that wouldn't run.)

Comment: There's really nothing you can do other than tell people to only use your tools with sites that have appropriate behavior.  Most sites these days use dynamically generated content, and there is rarely any relationship between "a url" and "a directory on the filesystem".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, when the server returns a "200 OK", then that means the URL does, in fact, exist and has the contents returned.  Those contents might be a page that says "This doesn't exist".  To identify that you would need to work on some artificial intelligence that can render and read the content that was returned and comprehend it like a human would.

I consider it bad web site design (and even worse for AJAX APIs) to always return "200 OK" and embed the "real" status in the payload, but that is how some people code it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib:

```
import requests
def checkDir(checkDir_target):
    breakurl = urlparse(target)
    response = requests.get(breakurl.netloc, headers=checkDir_target)
    complete = target + x
    if response.status < 400:
        print(" [X] " + complete)
        global total_resp
        total_resp += 1
        found.append(complete)
    else:
        print(" [ ] " + complete)
```

I think this can works for you.